# Error provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended

Tags: sql-server

I am running the below query

```
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO


USE Master;
Go
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[MK03] FROM OPENDatasource('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Data Source=C:\Users\sarita\Documents\ABC\abc.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Sheet1$];
```

But it is throwing the below error

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)
```

TCP/IP protocol is already enabled and Sql service is also running

I am using below version

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 18363: )
How i can resolve this

Comment: Is C:\Users\sarita\Documents\ABC\abc.xlsx currently open in Excel? Excel likes to take exclusive locks on files - which would prevent SQL Server from opening it - so close the file in Excel before trying to query it.

Comment: File is not open